# Crash while trying to sort a list

Tags: c, list, sorting, crash

I am learning C, so forgive me for any error. (and do the same for my bad english, since i am not english.)

I have to sort a numerical int list. This is the pseudocode, on how it should work:

```
/* it takes the minimum of the entire list and put on first position, than it takes the minimum of the entire list but starting from second position, and etc... */
while(list != null){
    min = minimum(list);
    swap(min->dato, list->dato);
    list = list->next;
}
```

I would know, why if I create a sorted list, the program crash?
Here, the entire program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct elemento{
       int dato;
       struct elemento *next;
};

struct elemento *crealista();
void printlista(struct elemento *);
struct elemento *ordinalista(struct elemento *);
struct elemento *minimo(struct elemento *);

main(){

    struct elemento * lista = crealista();

    printf("PRIMA: \n");
    printlista(lista);
    printf("DOPO: \n");
    printlista(ordinalista(lista));

    system("PAUSE"); 

}

void printlista(struct elemento *p){

     printf("START->");
     while(p != NULL){
             printf("%d->",p->dato);
             p = p->next;
     }
     printf("NULL \n");

}

struct elemento *minimo(struct elemento *p){
       int minimo = p->dato;
       struct elemento * ritorno;
       while(p != NULL){

             if(p->dato < minimo){ minimo = p->dato; ritorno = p;}


        p= p->next;       
       }
       return(ritorno);

}
struct elemento *ordinalista(struct elemento *p){
    bool flag = false;
    int temp;
    struct elemento * start = p;
    struct elemento * min;
         while(p != NULL){ 

              min = minimo(p);
              temp = p->dato;
              p->dato = min->dato;
              min->dato = temp;

          p=p->next;
         }

    return (start);
}

struct elemento *crealista(){
    struct elemento *p,*p2; 
    int i,n;
    p = (struct elemento *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento)); //p diventa un puntatore di tipo ELEMENTO, alla porzione di memoria restituita da malloc
    printf("Gimme first dato: "); scanf("%d",&p->dato);
    printf("\nHow many dato do u want?: "); scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n>0){
             p2 = p;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
              p2->next = (struct elemento *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
              p2 = p2->next;
              printf("\nGimme %d dato: ",i); scanf("%d",&p2->dato);
        }
        p2->next = NULL;
    }else{p->next = NULL;}
    return (p); 
}
```

Comment: Of course, the problem will be function ordinalista....

Comment: p is always not null

Comment: A small point, but it would be helpful if you could [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30616913/edit) your question to (a) spread your comments so they are visible without horizontal scrolling and (b) translate your Italian comment to English.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&p2->dato);` --> `scanf("%d",&p->dato);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `minimo()` is called on a sorted list, `if(p->dato < minimo)`is never true, so `{ minimo = p->dato; ritorno = p;}` is never executed, so `ritorno` is left uninitialized. Change the function to:

```
struct elemento *minimo(struct elemento *p){
       int minimo = p->dato;
       struct elemento * ritorno = p;   //this line changed!
       while(p != NULL){

             if(p->dato < minimo){ minimo = p->dato; ritorno = p;}


        p= p->next;       
       }
       return(ritorno);

}
```